# OpenCV cv::dft() iOS Assertion Error

Tags: iphone, xcode, opencv, fft, dft

I need some help in a bad way. I swear I have looked for now 1 week for an answer to this, and have been unsuccessful, so I come crawling for help.

My goal is simple. I am trying to use the OpenCV library in Xcode. I'm having some round about frustrating problem. I got the OpenCV library to work well with cvCanney and cvAdaptive Transforms, but I can't get it to do cv::dft(). I started by attempting the following:

```
cv::Mat tempMat = [self.imageView.image CVGrayscaleMat];
cv::dft(tempMat, output2);
```

This would error because it was not in the proper format (CV_32FC1). So I then tried:

```
cv::Mat tempMat = [self.imageView.image CVMat];
cv::cvtColor(tempMat, output2, CV_32FC1); 
cv::dft(output2, output3);
```

and I get the same error. Specifically the error reads:

`Assertion failed (type == CV_32FC1 || type == CV_32FC2 || type == CV_64FC1 || type == CV_64FC2) in dft`

As an update to the original question, I've been trying to determine the type using cv::type() and it returns a type=  24. Can anyone explain to me how to decipher what this type means? Is it the wrong type? Latest attempt:

```
cv::Mat tempMat = [self.imageView.image CVMat];
cv::Mat output2(tempMat.rows, tempMat.cols, CV_32FC1); 


cv::cvtColor(tempMat, tempMat, CV_32FC1); 


int type = tempMat.type();
int type2 = output2.type();
```

When I run this I get a type of 24 for tempMat, and a type of 5 for output2. If I try to add this:

```
cv::cvtColor(output2, output2, CV_32FC1);
```

I get error: `Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor`

Any ideas? Even if it a RTFM suggestion, I'll take anything at this point. Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a variable type and number of channels problem.

```
cv::Mat tempMat = [self.imageView.image CVMat];
cv::Mat output2;
cv::cvtColor(tempMat,output2, CV_BGR2GRAY);
output2.convertTo(output2, CV_32FC1);
cv::dft(output2, output2); 
output2.convertTo(image, CV_8UC1);
```

Please let me know if this works, I have a similar code in my project and tried to derive an answer from it; thus it may contain some errors. And we can work it through interactively from here.